# Can I merge three images into single for a background image of a button?

Tags: ios, button, background, uibutton, background-image

Here I'm in a situation, where I need to add three images to make a button.

We have three parts of an image the left mast part, the middle part and the right end part.

Left part of the image ->[image: Left part of the button.] Middle part of the image ->[image: Middle part of the button.] Right part of the image -> [image: Right part of the button.]

Since the text in the middle i.e the title of the button varies from button to button I dont want to create a seperate image with different dimensions everytime. I think there should be a way to merge these buttons to make one complete button depending on the width of the button provided.

[image]

When all is done, the complete button should look something like this.

I hope you got what I need. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can draw those images in the canvas and assign that image to your uibutton background.

Comment: @lakesh dude i meant to merge them programatically depending on the width of the button.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you use a stretchable image.

The image you make will be a single image with the left part, the middle part and the right part.

The middle part only needs to be a single pixel wide. (Imagine what your button would look like with only a tiny space between the two ends. That's your image.

Then you use this code...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];

UIImage *stretchableImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0];

[myButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This will then take that narrow image and take the pixel AFTER your cap width (i.e. 10 in this example) and it will repeat that single pixel the required number of times to get the full width of the button.

You can then reuse this single image everywhere no matter how small or big the buttons are.

Answer (score -1):

You can use button title label to set text while keeping the background image common.

eg :-   Works

```
      [btn setTitle:@"something" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setTitle:@"something" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
      [btn setTitle:@"something" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
      [btn setTitle:@"something" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

You can set image to button using the 
          setImage:forState method or setBackgrounImage:forState

eg :-
          btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
          [btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          //OR setting as background image

```
      [btnTwo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can use different font that is used in the image by using the font property of UIButton

eg :-     btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];

```
  //OR
```

You can also set the font size, and the font style using something like this. Its a little more than what your asking for but hey, what the heck...

```
      [btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];
```

And... If you're feeling frisky a list of available fonts can be found by implementing this code and then checking the output in your xCode debugger.

Code:

```
      NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
      NSArray *fontNames;
      NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
      for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
      {
      NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
      fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
        [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
        [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
      for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
      {
         NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
      }
      }
```

Comment: Just setting an image like this will stretch it to the right size but any rounded corners will be distorted by the stretch. The best way to do what he is asking is to use a stretchable image.

Comment: @Fogmeister : I agree with you, image gets stretched if the button size is large. But when dealing with buttons not varying much in size then he can use setBackgroundImage: and would work fine .

Comment: Still no. If you have rounded corners on your image with a corner radius of 8 then if the button is twice the width of the image you get a corner that is distorted with 8 vertically and 16 horizontally. It looks terrible. This happens if the image is smaller too. You can do it but why? It is so easy to use the proper method of stretchable image and it stops your UI from looking bad.

Comment: @Fogmeister I agreed on you point. Was mentioning for buttons without rounded borders. Yup using stretchable images is excellent :)